# templating virtual functions not possible. Only a temporary technical limitation?

Tags: c++, templates

I understand that you can't declare a virtual method as templated, because the compiler would not know how much entries to reserve in the virtual table. This is, however, a technical limitation, rather than a language one. The compiler could know how many instances of the template are actually needed, and "go back" to allocate a proper vtable size.

Is there a planned technical solution in the upcoming standard?

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you wish to accomplish (if the compiler limitation could be ignored).

Comment: Perhaps a more insightful approach is to ask what hoops one must jump through to make a similar mechanism work in current C++, and then how that process could be automated. After all, any desired final data structure is already within the expressive power of the language. The only problem is that `template<…> virtual` isn't the way to get there.

Comment: @Roee: Nothing in particular, just trying to understand the environment.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel *"Can you please give an example of what you wish to accomplish"* - Hmmm...maybe...to use virtual method templates?

Answer (score 4):

The compiler can never know all of the possible instantiations of a template. Under the current compilation model, each translation unit is compiled separately and later linked. When compiling a template type in one translation unit, you do not know the instantiations of that type in another.

Imagine you're writing a library and you want a template function in it. You compile the library and then distribute it to your clients. Now the clients can instantiate your template function with whatever template arguments they like, but your library has already been compiled! It can't "go back" and change this.

You're assuming that when you compile the template function, you also have available every instantiation of that function. That's often not the case and, under the current compilation and linking model, cannot be known to be the case.

Comment: Well, this is indeed true, but couldn't they solve with a dynamic vtable? I do understand the level of mess this requires though.

Comment: On the other hand, once you've built a complete program, the set of template instantiations has been fixed; in principle, the virtual metadata could be generated at that point, rather than when the base class is defined. So it's not an insurmountable obstacle, just one that would need a fundamental change to the compile/link model currently defined by the language (and even more changes if you want to support dynamic linking).

Comment: @StefanoBorini Sure, it *could* be solved. Nothing is impossible! It would require some quite hefty changes to the way that C++ programs are compiled and linked which would also need to be reflected in the standard.

Comment: It would also require to embed the source in one form or another. Just like with export. And export has been removed.

Comment: @MikeSeymour What is a complete program? Thinking about dlopen() and other dynamic loading facilities.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Not really. It would require computation of the vtable at DLL load time. Function *names* are already stored in DLL's, dynamic vtables would just require processing a little more info than is already there. `export` involved saving function *bodies* and that's quite different.

Comment: @johannes: Indeed, that's more complicated, as I noted at the end of my comment. It's still not insurmountable though; it would just need a much more complex linker.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: lets assume a library that implements some hypothetical pure virtual template function. It instantiates an object Derived that will override this function. Then you use that library and call `base->foo<T>()` on that object, with your own new type T. What code will be executed?

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's no different from calling a function template that may have been instantiated in a DLL. The ABI has to define the behavior of the function such that it behaves the same no matter whether it's instantiated when the DLL is compiled or when the client is compiled. The client needs the source code at compile time in a header file, not at load time in the DLL.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly **possible** to do this, given no requirements of working with existing linkers. That is, the linker could sift through all the instantiations of that template function and build the appropriate data structures. But one of the strengths of C++ is that it doesn't require specialized linkers; that makes it portable to systems where the linker is written in stone and cannot be changed. And, yes, that happens; the linker is where **all** the object code meets, and it has to be compatible with **all** the programming languages that the system supports, and that, in turn, means that it sometimes has grown old and crufty, and **any** change brings a substantial risk of breakage. So, while it's theoretically possible to do this, it ain't gonna happen.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing currently planned based on the C++ Standards Committee [papers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/) and [core language issues](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_toc.html).  The C++ Standard specifies requirements for implementations of C++, but not define the technical implementation itself.  Hence, template virtual functions are explicitly not a technical limitation, but rather a limitation of the language defined by the standard.  Nevertheless, the limitation of the language may be the result of the risk involved in changing existing implementations rather than being imposed as a result of an implementation's technical limitations.